# Deploying Windowsform application with SqlServer 2012 Databse in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

How can I deploy a windows form application with sql server database. I've searched a lot, The problem is I want the actual .mdf file when the application got installed on a PC for backup purposes. When I tried the publish feature, it converts the .mdf file into .mdf.deploy. I don't want to attach it into Sql Server Management Studio. I want to publish it with the actual application as .mdf, Kindly guide me in right direction. Thanks

Comment: Do you need to share the database with other users?

Comment: Attempting to manage a SQL database in this fashion will be difficult.  It's not like Access where it's canned and portable.  If all you have is an MDF file, how might you access it?  Don't you need SqlServer to provide a connection/database for you to reference?

Comment: yes, I want to save it as well in some other location for backup purposes. @Steve

Comment: No, I have asked about the share, meaning if you plan to instal the database in a client/server model. Other users should work on the same database from different PC.

Comment: nope! only on one pc! only client/server model

Answer (score 1):

If you nose around on the MS SQL Server site, you find that you can include a 'silent installer' for SQL Server in your .NET project.  This will download and install an instance of SQL Server Express as part of your installation process. Just having the .MDF in a folder is useless.

In effect, you have to make at least a few items of functionality that stand in for SSMS: in particular database backups, database compaction, DBCC CHECKDB, etc.  You are installing a 'full blown' SQL server instance, with it's separate windows service and system account, so you should be aware of how that impacts your user machine.  This gets interesting if it's being deployed to a laptop, particularly a laptop that might sit in a café exposing ports to public LANs.

In general this is a can of worms.  It is better to mandate the installation of SQL Server Express first, with SSMS, and merely attach your database to the existing instance.  This makes a lot of other operations better behaved.